# PostgreSQL - Monitoring table size during insert

Tags: postgresql

I am constructing a table using a PostgreSQL function. Is there a way to monitor the size of the table while the function is still running?

Comment: Did you try something from this page? [link](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/05/15-advanced-postgresql-commands-with-examples) Especially point 3 may be interested.

Comment: Never thought of this before. But i am curious. Why would you want to do this?

Comment: To monitor how the insertion is going.

Comment: How long are you expecting the insert to take?  Most inserts take milliseconds, unless your table has to reorg indexes, especially clustered indexes.

Comment: @Nick: Can you explain what clustered indexes have to do with it? Especially given the fact that Pg doesn't have them?

Comment: @depesz Well, then I'm just showing my ignorance with Pg aren't I.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
watch "psql -c \"select pg_relation_size('yourtable')\""
```